# Cannot disable R markdown output from gridExtra (additional cases)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, r-markdown, gridextra

When I knit

````
```{r DATASNAPSHOT1, echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.height=10, fig.width=10}
    plot1 <- grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p0, p1,ncol=2), p2, ncol=1, heights=c(1.5,2))
    plot1
'''
````

to R markdown (html), the plots display as intended but beneath it I get the unwanted

```
## TableGrob (2 x 1) "arrange": 2 grobs
##   z     cells    name            grob
## 1 1 (1-1,1-1) arrange gtable[arrange]
## 2 2 (2-2,1-1) arrange  gtable[layout]
```

in my output.

**How do I get rid if it in my r markdown?**

I've lookd at this answer [Cannot disable R markdown output from gridExtra (additional comment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268103/cannot-disable-r-markdown-output-from-gridextra-additional-comment)
but it doesn't work in my case.

I tried"

```
plot1 <- grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p0, p1,ncol=2), p2, ncol=1, heights=c(1.5,2))
grid.draw(plot1)
```

and

```
plot1 <- arrangeGrob(arrangeGrob(p0, p1,ncol=2), p2, ncol=1, heights=c(1.5,2))
grid.draw(plot1)
```

and

```
plot1 <- arrangeGrob(p0, p1,ncol=2)
plot2 <- arrangeGrob(p2, ncol=1)
grid.draw(plot1, plot2, heights=c(1.5,2))
```

but none work.

Comment: @Imo: I have - will add this to the question.thx

Comment: Do you really need `grid.arrange`? You can try `cowplot::plot_grid` or `egg::ggarrange` to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

`plot1` gets printed; remove it from the chunk if you don't want to see it printed.